# Upgraded Blazor to ..NET 6. Can't publish to linux server anymore

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, .net-6.0

Just upgraded my Blazor project to .NET 6 and everything is working perfectly locally but I can't publish anymore.

I get the following error while trying to publish:

> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.6_0.targets(412, 5): [MSB4044] The "ComputeBlazorPublishAssets" task was not given a value for the required parameter "DotNetJsVersion".

When I double click ton this error message, I'm  sent to the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.6_0.targets target file where I have to following code:

```
<ComputeBlazorPublishAssets
      ResolvedFilesToPublish="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)"
      TimeZoneSupport="$(_BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport)"
      PublishPath="$(PublishDir)"
      WasmAotAssets="@(WasmNativeAsset)"
      InvariantGlobalization="$(_BlazorInvariantGlobalization)"
      CopySymbols="$(CopyOutputSymbolsToPublishDirectory)"
      ExistingAssets="@(_BlazorPublishPrefilteredAssets)"
      DotNetJsVersion="$(_DotNetJsVersion)"
    >
  <Output TaskParameter="NewCandidates" ItemName="_NewBlazorPublishStaticWebAssets" />
  <Output TaskParameter="FilesToRemove" ItemName="_PublishResolvedFilesToRemove" />
</ComputeBlazorPublishAssets>
```

I'm kind of stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share *your* project file?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?
I encountered the same problem using JetBrains Rider 2021.3 EAP 10, but I found that with Visual Studio 2022 Preview publishing works.

Comment: I'm also using Rider 2021.3 EAP 10. Good to know. I got it working by publishing with self contained option. Would still prefer the framework dependent option.

Comment: I checked with an empty project and got the same error, so I created a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-71884).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when deploying docker, and I changed it to this:

```
RUN dotnet publish "Administration.Blazor.csproj" -a $TARGETARCH -c Release -o /app/publish --self-contained true /p:UseAppHost=false
```